# How to import data stored in an Access Query into SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I want to import all data (columns/rows) stored in an access query called "T4-R01"

i am trying to do use the following syntax in SQL Server management 2008:

```
select Month from OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data Source=c:\EatonFAS109Q12012.mdb;User ID=;Password=')...[T4-R01]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message    "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

Am i using the correct syntax? any suggestions?

Comment: I reckon this is a permissions problem, see http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=16512&p=76579&hilit=linked+server#p76579 and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/c3c96917-e93e-4db9-a91c-efd5ec30152c